# How to remove padding and margin from my html content?

Tags: html, css, margin

[image]

I have tried :

```
body{ 
     margin:0px; 
     padiing:0px
}
```

and also

```
*{ 
   margin:0px; 
   padiing:0px
 }
```

Please give some other solution

Comment: can we have a fiddle or a link (if it is live)

Comment: post a fiddle. also no need to use `px` or any notations for `0` values

Comment: @ChandraShekhar He is required to post a minimal markup of the problem here, not a fiddle: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few things causing this to not work.

1. You are missing a semi-colon at the end of each padding property.
2. You are spelling padding wrong. It should be `padding: 0px;`
3. Make sure you are referencing your css file in your head tag as such `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path to css file here">`